# Angularjs $resource multiple POST

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-resource

I have multiple `Web Api Post methods` like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] AdModel adModel)
    {
        //Post
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AddToWatchList")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddToWatchList(int adId)
    {
        // Post to database
    }
```

Here is my AngularJs Server:

```
app.factory('adService', ['$resource', 'ngAuthSettings', function ($resource, ngAuthSettings) {

      var serviceBase = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri;

return $resource(serviceBase + 'api/Ads/', {}, {
            addToWatchList: {
            method: 'POST',
            url: serviceBase + 'api/Ads/addToWatchList'
           }
        }
    });
}]);
```

**AngularJs Controller:**

```
app.controller('listCategoryAdsController',
    ['ngAuthSettings', '$scope', 'adService', '$routeParams', '$location',
    function (ngAuthSettings, $scope, adService, $routeParams, $location) {

    $scope.addToWatchlist = function (adId) {
        adService.addToWatchList({ adId: adId }).$promise.then(
            function(result) {
                var path = $location.path();
                $location.path(path).search('nw', 1);
            },
            function (error) {

        });
    };
```

**My Html from where I am calling method:**

```
<div class="col-sm-3 text-right price-box" data-ng-repeat="ad in Ads">
     <h2 class="item-price">
         $ {{ad.price}}
     </h2>
     <i class="fa fa-certificate">
     </i>
     <a ng-click="addToWatchlist(ad.adId)" class="btn btn-default  btn-sm make-favorite" tooltip="Click to add to watch list"
           tooltip-placement="left"
           tooltip-trigger="mouseenter">
          <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
           <span>Watch list</span>
     </a>
</div>
```

My problem is `Post([FromBody] AdModel adModel)` is being called perfectly. But when I call `AddToWatchList(int adId)` I am getting :

> POST http://localhost:8081/api/Ads/addToWatchList 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What is the base route set on the server webapi controller? Also can you rename the webapi function to `PostAddToWatchList` and try.

Comment: Base route is [RoutePrefix("api/Ads")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a simple type (int) to AddToWatchList(), therefore Web API is looking in the URI for the adId parameter.

> If the parameter is a **“simple” type, Web API tries to get the value
>   from the URI**. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (**int**,
>   bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal,
>   and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from
>   a string. (More about type converters later.) **For complex types, Web
>   API tries to read the value from the message body**, using a media-type
>   formatter.
>   [More on this..](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

You have a few options:

1 - Send adId through the URI... *api/ads/addtowatchlist?adId=123*

```
$resource(serviceBase + 'api/Ads/addToWatchList', { }, {
    addToWatchList: { method:'POST', params:{ adId:adId } }
});
```

---

2 - Obviously use a complex object as you are doing in the first method. Although it feels silly having a class with a single int property... this is why you and I don't like this approach. But if you already have an Ad class, nothing wrong with reusing it.

---

3 - Try [this solution](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data,-part-1#sending_simple_types) which requires in which you would add [FromBody] to your int parameter. And send the adId in with no identifier

```
=123
```